# Having issues with code now giving expected output

Tags: c++

Having issues getting this graded properly. It keeps showing up as 87% out of 100, but all of the prerequisites are functioning as they should. The program is supposed to take a number of cookies and determine how many cookies, boxes, and containers are to be used along with outputting the remainder in the event there is one. Clearly, I'm missing something, but I cannot figure out what.

> 24 cookies in a box.
>
> 75 boxes in a container.

https://pastebin.com/HURqViSB (if needed)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Write your main here

    int cookies;
    int leftoverCookies;
    int boxes;
    int leftoverBoxes;
    int containers;

    cout << "Please enter the total number of cookies: ";
    cin >> cookies;

    if (cookies == 24) {
        boxes = 1;
        leftoverCookies = 0;
        cout << endl
             << "The number of boxes used: " << boxes;
        cout << endl
             << "The number of leftoverCookies is: " << leftoverCookies;
    }
    else if (cookies < 24) {
        leftoverCookies = cookies;
        boxes = 0;
        cout << endl
             << "The number of boxes used: " << boxes;
        cout << endl
             << "The number of leftover cookies is: " << leftoverCookies;
    }

    else if (cookies > 24) {
        boxes = (cookies / 24);
        cout << endl
             << "The number of boxes used: " << boxes;
        leftoverCookies = (cookies % 24);
        cout << endl
             << "The number of leftover cookies is: " << leftoverCookies;
    }

    if (boxes == 75) {
        containers = 1;
        leftoverBoxes = 0;
        cout << endl
             << "The number of containers used: " << containers;
        cout << endl
             << "The number of leftover boxes: " << leftoverBoxes;
    }
    else if (boxes < 75) {
        containers = 0;
        leftoverBoxes = 0;
        cout << endl
             << "The number of containers used: " << containers;
        cout << endl
             << "The number of leftover boxes: " << leftoverBoxes;
    }

    else if (boxes > 75) {
        containers = (boxes / 75);
        cout << endl
             << "The number of containers used: " << containers;
        leftoverBoxes = (boxes % 75);
        cout << endl
             << "The number of leftover boxes is: " << leftoverBoxes;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the input you give, and the expected and actual output. I also recommend you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line.

Comment: By the way, when you print the number of boxes and leftover cookies, you have different output depending on which branch you take. Should it not be the same in all three branches?

Comment: The input is any number really.  It could be 1, 0, 24, or 29405.  The program is producing the correct numbers, but for some reason, the grading keeps giving it 87/100.  


As you can see in the bottom right of this imgur link, even the expected output is proper?

https://imgur.com/a/BkSKd

Also, thank you for the link on how to debug small programs.  Quite useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're kind of missing the point of this exercise - you don't need a single conditional, only `/` and `%`.

Incidentally, getting rid of the conditionals also fixes the bug when `boxes < 75` and you set `leftoverBoxes = 0` instead of `leftoverBoxes = boxes` as it should be.

You only need something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int cookies = 0;
    cout << "Please enter the total number of cookies: ";
    cin >> cookies;

    int boxes = cookies / 24;
    int leftoverCookies = cookies % 24;

    int containers = boxes / 75;
    int leftoverBoxes = boxes % 75;

    cout << endl
         << "The number of boxes used: " << boxes;
    cout << endl
         << "The number of leftover cookies is: " << leftoverCookies;
    cout << endl
         << "The number of containers used: " << containers;
    cout << endl
         << "The number of leftover boxes: " << leftoverBoxes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this line

```
else if (boxes < 75) {
    containers = 0;
    leftoverBoxes = 0;
```

instead read...

```
else if (boxes < 75) {
    containers = 0;
    leftoverBoxes = boxes;
```

?, As there are not enough boxes to add to a container, the left over boxes should simply be the total amount of boxes